# Q: How do I concatenate str + int to = an existing variable

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, concatenation

I want to combine a str + int to equal a existing variable that I already defined. I tried looking up on how this can be done and I've only found how to concatenate a str and int together with

```
print "var%d" % currentIndex
```

what I have is currentIndex being the index number of the selection in a PyQt4 combo box. I related the index number of the combo box selection to a large file full of var0 - var30. Each one being a list of information that I want to pull on demand when ever currentIndex is changed.

```
var0 = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
( user picks a selection from GUI comboBox )
print "var%d" % currentIndex 
var0
```

It's not printing the list it's just printing the var0 as a string. How do I get the two to equal var0 the variable and not var0 the str?

Comment: Are you trying to *compute* the name of the variable you wish to print, and then print that?  That is, if `currentIndex`=0, you want to print the contents of `var0`?

Comment: you can use function eval()  https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval

Comment: print eval("var0")

Comment: Yes Scott Hunter I want it so that when currentIndex  = 0 the list var0 is called and printed rather then just a simple string "var0" so when I type print it'll print the list attached to var0 variable and not the word var0

Comment: GpG how do I make it so the # in var is dynamic every time the user changes the index in that print?

Comment: Moses Koledoye I tried that and it just says var is not defined

Comment: Like in so many similar questions before, the proper solution is to use a key into a dict rather than a variable name for the indirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print the list like this:

```
print eval("var%d" % currentIndex)
```

But I would suggest you to use a nested list rather than 30 variables:

```
var = [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["e", "f"], ...]
print var[currentIndex]
```

Comment: This is perfect!! I'm going to go with the second option then seems a lot cleaner and less lines. How would I go about pulling a specific item from a nested list? The way I did that with a normal list was with

L = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
print [ L[index] for index in [1,3,5] ]

Comment: Just add another index like `var[i][j]`. E.g. `var[1][0]` would result in `"e"` for the example above.